# MySQL/PHP ignoring existing users (sometimes)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, security, request

When I spam the registration button a lot and keep swapping usernames (FAST!) sometimes theres' duplicates in my database. If I do it slow, there's no duplicates.

Is it possible that the username check is too far before the `createUser` in the logic and that one script is still handling the logic inbetween while the other just passes the check? If so, is not every web application vulnerable to this type of attack assuming your requests are fast enough? How can you stop this?

Hopefully someone can help :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either ensure only one query fired upon multiple user clicking the button (which is impossible) or make a constraint in database - make the column **unique** or **primary key**, personally i suggest using unique instead.

Database-check much better and less code. However you'll need to catch every insertion error and throw feedbacks to user that the username already taken or so.